# Two values in dictionary wihile using linq json c#

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am not able to add two values while creating JSON.
I am using LINQ to obtain results in the data table can you please help?

***Datatable data.***

```
+-----------------+----------------------------------------+-----------+
|       Key       |                 Value                  | filetype  |
+-----------------+----------------------------------------+-----------+
| Sorry           | UNDSKYLD!                              | Associate |
| ValSpace        | Mellemrum er ikke tilladt              | Associate |
| UpdtProfile_Sub | Актуализация на потребителски профил   | Emails    |
| UplineMail_msg  | Моля, потвърдете Нивото на потребителя | Emails    |
+-----------------+----------------------------------------+-----------+
```

***what I have tried.***

```
        DataTable dt = fillDataTable();
        var target = dt.AsEnumerable()
.Select(row => new clsTranslation
{
    Key = row.Field<string>(0) != null ? row.Field<string>(0) : "",
    Value = row.Field<string>(1) != null ? row.Field<string>(1) : "",
    filetype = row.Field<string>(2) != null ? row.Field<string>(2) : ""
}).ToList();

        Dictionary<string, List<string>> test =
               target
              .GroupBy(r => r.filetype)
              .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Select(r => r.Key)
              .ToList());

        string newjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

***received result.***

```
      {
        "Associate": {
          "Sorry",
          "ValSpace",
      },
          "Emails": {
          "UpdtProfile_Sub",
          "UplineMail_msg",
      }
```

***expected result.***

```
     {
        "Associate": {
          "Sorry": "UNDSKYLD! ",
          "ValSpace": "Mellemrum er ikke tilladt  ",
      },
          "Emails": {
          "UpdtProfile_Sub": "Актуализация на потребителски профил ",
          "UplineMail_msg": "Моля, потвърдете Нивото на потребителя",
      }

    }
```

Comment: `Value` is never put in `test` how do you expect it to get into `newjson`? Replace second parameter to `ToDictionary` with `t => t.ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Value)`.

Comment: You could alternatively use a anonymous* object to create a similar effect to @NetMage above. `var test =  d.GroupBy(r => r.FileType).ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value }).ToList());`

Comment: @DekuDesu I think you mean anonymous type (or object) :)

Comment: @DekuDesu with your code I am getting output in another format.i.e "Associate": [ { "Key": "Address", "Value": "Адрес" }

Comment: @NetMage: can you please help me with what needs to replace

Comment: I am able to achieve the same by using  var test = target.GroupBy(r => r.filetype)
                .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t
                .Select(x => new{x.Key, x.Value }).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
                );

Comment: You don't need the intermediate anonymous object: `t` already has `Key` and `Value` fields: `g => g.ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `Dictionary<,>` to hold the intermediate objects:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> test =
       target
      .GroupBy(r => r.filetype)
      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you don't want a Dictionary but a Lookup Table, an object that implements [interface ILookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.ilookup-2?view=net-5.0).

ILookup is similar to a Dictionary<TKey, IEnumerable>, so if you have a key, the Lookup will give you the zero or more values that belong to this key.

If you have an enumerable sequence of similar items you can create a Lookup table using one of the overloads of [Enumerable.ToLookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=net-5.0)

Because you might want to fetch your `ClsTranslations` for other things than your Lookup Table, I separate fetching the ClsTranslations from putting them in your "Dictionary".

```
IEnumerable<ClsTranslation> FetchClsTranslations()
{
    return fillDataTable().AsEnumerable()
        .Select(row => new clsTranslation
        {
            Key = row.Field<string>(0) ?? String.Empty,
            Value = row.Field<string>(1) ?? String.Empty,
            FileType = row.Field<string>(2) ?? String.Empty,
        });
}
```

I took the liberty to change your lines `row.Field<string>(0) != null ? row.Field<string>(0) : ""`, I use the [null coalescing operator (??)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

> The null-coalescing operator ?? returns the value of its left-hand operand if it isn't null; otherwise, it evaluates the right-hand operand and returns its result.

```
Key = row.Field<string>(0) ?? String.Empty,
```

In other words, if `row.Field<string>(0)` is not null, use this value, otherwise use `String.Empty`.

The advantage of separating fetching your data from handling the fetched data, makes the code easier to read, easier to reuse, and easier to change (no one outside this function will have to change if your data comes from a CVS file, or a database), and easier to unit test.

Now to create your lookup table:

```
var target = FetchClsTranslations().ToLookup(clsTranslation => clsTranslation.FileType);
```

Usage:

"Give me all ClsTranslations that have FileType == Emails

```
const requestedFileType = Emails;
IEnumerable<ClsTranslation> requestedClsTranslations = target[requestedFileType];
```

That's all!

This lookup table has per fileType all ClsTranslations that have this fileType.

If you really don't want this, but want a lookup with combination of {Key, Value} as values, use the overload of ToLookup that uses parameter elementSelector:

```
var target = FetchClsTranslations().ToLookup(
    // parameter keySelector:
    clsTranslation => clsTranslation.FileType,

    // parameter elementSelector: the values of the lookup is {Key, Value}
    clsTranslation => new
    {
        Key = clsTranslation.Key,
        Value = clsTranslation.Value,
    });
```

Now you have a different lookup: give me a FileType as key, and I'll give you als {Key, Value} combinations that belonged to a ClsTranslation that had this key.

Usage:

```
const requestedFileType = Emails;
var requestedKeyValues = target[requestedFileType];
```

requenstedKeyValues is a sequence of objects, where every object has a property Key and a property Value.

The most important difference with a Lookup Table and a Dictionary, is that you can't change it: you can't add, nor remove items from the lookup table. If you really want to do this, add ToDictionary.

```
var target = FetchClsTranslations().ToLookup(...)
    .ToDictionary(lookupItem => lookupItem.Key, lookupItem => lookupItem
```

ILookup also implements `IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<TKey,TElement>>`, so you can get the Key of every element in the Lookup. Every element of an IGrouping **is** a sequence, not **has** a sequence. so `lookupItem => lookupItem` to select the values of the dictionary